# Demonstrate: $M_p=2^p-1$

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes

Demonstrate:

If the number $M_p=2^p-1$  is Composite number, where $p$ is prime, then $M_p$ is a Pseudoprime.

This exercise was on a test and I could not do!!

Number Pseudoprime:
Fermat's little theorem states that if p is prime and a is coprime to p, then $a^{p−1} − 1$ is divisible by p. For an integer a > 1, if a composite integer x divides $a^{x−1} − 1$, then x is called a Fermat pseudoprime to base a. It follows that if x is a Fermat pseudoprime to base a, then x is coprime to a. Some sources use variations of this definition, for example to only allow odd numbers to be pseudoprimes

Comment: what is a pseudo prime?

Comment: ckeck it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime

Comment: There are many different definitions of pseudoprime, as you can see in your Wikipedia link. Which one are you working with?

Comment: o i didnt know,, im sorry!!!

Comment: It is pseudoprime to the base $2$.

Answer (score 6):

More precisely, $M_p$ is a pseudoprime to the base $2$. To show this we show that 
$$2^{M_p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{M_p}.$$
By Fermat's Theorem we have $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Thus $2^{p-1}=1+kp$ for some integer $k$, and therefore $M_p-1=2kp$. Thus 
$$2^{M_p-1}=(2^p)^{2k}=(1+M_p)^{2k}\equiv 1\pmod{M_p}.$$

Comment: Would u plz clarify more how $(2^p)^2k = (1+M)^2k $ ?

Comment: Since $M_p = 2^p-1$, we have $M_p+1 = 2^p$